# WCF or Asp.Net MVC for API acess?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, api

I wanted to get some thoughts about API access either through WCF or MVC. Either works, but I like the idea of using MVC to build custom routes. I know this is possible with WCF (maintaining the request routes), but aside form the security disadvantages of *not* using WCF (which are not deal breakers) what other thoughts does the community have regarding this.

I have a project where we have been discussion using MVC or WCF and we are comfortable with both, but we are swaying towards MVC.

Comment: Have you considered using the new [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) present in MVC4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the new ASP.Net MVC Web API framework, new to MVC 4.0.

Comment: This.  I've been wanting to use it, it looks so so simple to quickly build an API.

Comment: I was reading about this and that is why I commented on MVC3. Since everything is still in RC I am hesitant to put anything in production. I know I should, but I want to wait until the full release.

Answer (score 1):

I think MVC makes a great web API. I did this not too long ago for an android app that uses a RESTful web API using MVC 3. Here's a good tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx

If you're feeling adventurous check out the Web API framework included in MVC 4. NOTE: I have not experimented with this yet but plan to in the near future. See here: http://www.asp.net/web-api